# Использование препроцессоров на сервере (Bitrix, wordpress)

Tags: вёрстка, sass, frontend

Приветствую!

Для разработки front-end локально использую grunt c разными плагинами, такими как конкатенация и сжатие Js, создание спрайтов, компиляция SASS в CSS, компиляция Jade в HTML. Автопрефиксы. Переменные со спрайтами и прочее полезные фишки.

Но вот приходит момент интеграции верстки в битрикс или вордпресс. Дальнейшая работа ведется на сервере. Внесение правок и доработок в верстку сразу в двух местах (локально с дальнейшим переносом на сервер) - это явно не бест практик.

Хотелось бы знать, можно ли компилировать хотя бы SASS на хостинге, не имея полного контроля над сервером, только доступ к файлам и БД.

Comment: Что если использовать browser-sync и настроить на нужный сервер?!
Тогда можно спокойно все делать, а компиляция автоматически будет происходить и обновляться на сервере.

Comment: А вариант чистой компиляции есть? Например нашел компонент для Битрикса http://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/olegpro.csscompiler/#tab-install-link

Comment: ну почему не настроить автозагрузку по ftp ?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ftp

Comment: @VladimirFedulkin, такого не знаю) А вот с gulp (grunt) можно все сразу  делать (автопрефиксы, минификация, компиляция ... ) и сразу на сервер все отправлять. И да вот можно с gulp-ftp вариант.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko а можете привести пример такой конфигурации для галпа?

Comment: @u_mulder, что Вы имеете ввиду под "конфигурацией"? Если сборка, то их уже сейчас в интернете очень много, можно выбрать для себя уже готовый вариант. Сборка будет осуществлять вышеуказанные действия. Если об ftp, то https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ftp тут все описано как воспользоваться данным плагином (кстати для grunt такой плагин тоже имеется).
Для browser sync https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp, тоже есть описание и примеры.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Под конфигурацией я имею в виду параметры для настройки bs для работы на удаленном сервере.

Comment: @u_mulder, https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

Comment: Все же самым адекватным решением стало внедрение gulp/grunt в шаблон битрикса/вордпресса. Настроил так, чтобы в дальнейшей работе не менять структуру каталогов с конечными стилями, скриптами и спрайтами. Пока все утраивает и без костылей с велосипедами.

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы советовал Вам перейти на Gulp - очень много гибкости в настройке. 
А то что Вам нужно - то это плагин gulp-ftp 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ftp

Comment: Да, новый шаблон написал уже на Gulp. Он и быстрее в сборке оказался.